# Detecting if a object is owned by a smart pointer

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a class which derives from enable_shared_from_this and a method which returns a shared pointer by calling shared_from_this().  I would like to in that method detect if the object is owned by a shared_ptr and if not throw.  I tried something like this:

```
shared_ptr<T> getPointer() {
    shared_ptr<T> ptr(shared_from_this()));
    if(!ptr)
        throw "Not owned by smart pointer"
    return ptr;
}
```

This doesn't work though because a bad weak pointer exception is thrown during the construction of ptr. Is there another way.

Comment: can't you catch the exception?

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably being stupid, but it sounds like you don't have a problem: you wanted to throw an exception in a certain situation, and then you found that an exception is already being thrown in that situation, so you don't actually have to do anything special. No?

Comment: I really don't like having try catch blocks in the library. Just as wrappers on the applications.

Comment: Yes and no :).  I want to specialize the exception and give it a different text then what boost throws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the interface in the standard, I can't see anything which would do a decent test. Of course, you can always hack around the problem:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> getPointer() {
    try {
        return this->shared_from_this());
    }
    catch (std::bad_weak_ptr const&) {
        throw std::runtime_error("not owned by smart pointer");
    }
}
```

Of course, you could as well just not catch the `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception and have the original exception escape the function.

BTW, when throwing an exceptin it is trongly advised to throw an exception derived from `std::exception`. If you ever got an exception you know nothing you'll curse the guy who created it because it isn't always easy to get hold of that exception to find out what it is about (although debuggers can help, if necessary by setting a break point into the internal function throwing the exception). It is much easier to just write the result of `what()`.

Comment: As I mentioned in an above comment, I try to avoid try catch on the library side.I know about the exception.  That was just shorthand for SO.  The actual code throws a std::runtime_error.

Answer (score 3):

One of the preconditions of calling `shared_from_this()` for an object `t` is "there must exist at least one `shared_ptr` instance `p` that owns `t`" (see [the Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html)).  The C++11 specification of `enable_shared_from_this` has the same requirement.

As there are no other (documented) members of `enable_shared_from_this`, it appears there is no way to test whether an object derived from `enable_shared_from_this` is actually owned by a `shared_ptr`.

That said, for the sake of clarity, it would probably be best to derive from `enable_shared_from_this` only if objects of that type will always be owned by a `shared_ptr`.  That way there is no confusion.

Comment: But there is no way to enforce this explicitly though.  The closest is make the constructors private and make a factory method which returns a smart pointer to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Fortunately C++17 added "weak_from_this", which is helpful since it provides a copy of the weak_ptr from within `std::enable_shared_from_this` regardless of whether the instance is being managed from a shared pointer.

Simply checking if `this->weak_from_this().expired()` (which is the same as checking `use_count() == 0` according to the standard) appears to do the trick.

To the person reading this in 2034, hope it helps!